# BackgroundWorker using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

I am totally lost. I just seem to get no response from it.

```
    BackgroundWorker NewWorker;

    public void StartBackgroundWorker()
    {
        BackgroundWorker NewWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        NewWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(NewWorker_DoWork);
        NewWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(NewWorker_ProgressChanged);
        NewWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(NewWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        NewWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        StartWorker();
    }

    void NewWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
        {
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select StatusCode from Win32_PingStatus where address = 'Metabox-PC'");
                ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = searcher.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject Results in objCollection)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Results.ToString());
                }
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
            }
        }
    }

    private void NewWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Finished");
    }
```

None of the message boxes appear, indicating it's finished.
What have I missed?

Comment: What does `StartWorker` do?

Comment: Isn't the BackgroundWorker on a different thread than the UI ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755519/in-a-winforms-application-how-can-you-run-a-messagebox-from-a-background-worker#

Comment: @FrancisDucharme The worker itself isn't on any thread.  It is firing events in several different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never calling `RunWorkerAsync` on the `BackgroundWorker` that you have configured.

You *think* you are, because you're calling `StartWorker` which, (I presume) contains the code  `NewWorker.RunWorkerAsync();` somewhere in it, however `NewWorker`, inside of `StartWorker`, is referring to an entirely different `BackgroundWorker` that you have not configured to do anything.

You have an instance field, `NewWorker`, and a local variable `NewWorker` inside of `StartBackgroundWorker` that is shadowing the instance field.

If you really need the background worker to be an instance field, then don't shadow it in `StartBackgroundWorker` and use the instance field throughout.  If you don't need it to be an instance field (which, for the record, is likely, and needlessly promoting variables to instance fields makes for messier programs) then you simply need to start the `BackgroundWorkder` you created in  `StartBackgroundWorker`.  If `StartWorker` really has enough code that it needs to be in another method, then it probably means it should accept a `BackgroundWorker` as a parameter, so you can pass in the worker you created in `StartBackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never start your NewWorker. That's because your "global" NewWorker is always null.

See the fixed code:

```
    NewWorker = new BackgroundWorker(); // this line is now fixed.
    NewWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(NewWorker_DoWork);
    NewWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(NewWorker_ProgressChanged);
    NewWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(NewWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    NewWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    StartWorker();
```

Comment: To clarify a little further, you defined a new, local `NewWorker` variable in the function. Presumably, you meant to use the global variable defined in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to make the background worker a field? Just make it in the constructor and everything else like. In its events you can just cast the object as the BackgroundWorker.

```
public void StartBackgroundWorker()
{
    BackgroundWorker NewWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    NewWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(NewWorker_DoWork);
    NewWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(NewWorker_ProgressChanged);
    NewWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(NewWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    NewWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    NewWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Francis is right... Any attempt to call MessageBox in a thread other than the GUI thread will block. You'll have to invoke:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}));
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the question at all 2) What makes you think he doesn't want the call to `Show` to block?

Comment: @Servy 1) Actually I'm the only one that is answering his question. I stated that attempting to call MessageBox outside the GUI thread will block, this is the reason why his completed handler (which does occur on the main thread) isn't getting called, because it's blocking on the first MessageBox. 2) he very well could be but that's wasn't his question. His question is why his completed handler isn't getting called.

Comment: The completed handler isn't being called because the BGW with the completed handler is never being started.  If it *were* being started then he would be seeing message boxes, indicating progress, even though he has said he is not, it's just that the BGW would continue doing work while a bunch of calls to messagebox.show are piling up in the message pump.

Comment: That actually isn't how MessageBox works, there's a good CodeProject article about all this at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121226/MessageBoxes-and-worker-threads. I'll admit that I'm making the assumption his call to StartWorker() calls NewWorker.RunWorkerAsync() to start the thread, if you try doing a MessageBox in the thread func immediately then you'll see that it blocks. This is what's actually happening, his worker thread is trying to pop up message boxes to report progress and he's getting a deadlock.

Comment: Yes, it would block the BGW while waiting for the message box, but it would be able to be shown properly, so there is no deadlock, there is simply a shown message box waiting for the user to click it.  If he has some code somewhere that's not shown that is causing his UI to block, then yes, the message box isn't shown, but there is no evidence to support that assertion, and there *is* evidence of another problem, namely that you're making the assumption that `StartWorker` calls `NewWorker.RunWorkerAsync()`.  It may have that code, but it's still not executing any of the code shown here.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely correct. While chopping around with his code I introduced a deadlock myself. Doh! :) One thing that might be worth mentioning though is that if you do start a MessageBox in a worker thread it doesn't seem to get focus and can be hiding behind the main window and just might not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all your answers. The description supplied makes more sense to me now.

Also to the previous debate: the message box does block the thread. It got stuck at 10% and then crashed my computer (VM box).

Now my only issue is that `e.results` is returning an array of items. But it is in object.

I am finding it difficult to get the data back.

```
public void StartBackgroundWorker()
{

    BackgroundWorker NewWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    NewWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(NewWorker_DoWork);
    NewWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(NewWorker_ProgressChanged);
    NewWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(NewWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    NewWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    NewWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void NewWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> ReturnResults = new List<string>();
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select StatusCode from Win32_PingStatus where address = 'Metabox-PC'");
    ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject Results in objCollection)
    {
        ReturnResults.Add(Results["StatusCode"].ToString());
    }
    e.Result = ReturnResults;

    // Perform a time-consuming operation and report progress.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
}

private void NewWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    txtPingable.text = e.Result;
}
```