# c# - Pass string between voids and update in timer

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I pass and update the "MessageBox.Show" with ClientVersion so it will update every time when timer is starting?
I also would like to pass the server version for future use.

```
private void UpdateCheck()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://localhost/update/update_version.txt");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string ServerVersion = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string ClientVersion = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("update_version.txt");

}

private void UpdateCheckTimer()
{
    


    if (starter.Enabled == true)
    {



        Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 1500 }; // Interval is miliseconds
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(ClientVersion);
        timer.Start();


    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged asp.net? This doesn't make sense for asp.net.

Comment: Already asked, you are trying to run the messagebox on a background thread and push updates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755519/in-a-winforms-application-how-can-you-run-a-messagebox-from-a-background-worker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a winforms application, how can you run a messagebox from a background worker that must always be in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755519/in-a-winforms-application-how-can-you-run-a-messagebox-from-a-background-worker)

Comment: you cannot change a messagebox´ text once it´s created. You can however create and show a new one.

Comment: It doesn't look like that code *saves* anything to a file named "update_version.txt" (even without the full path which should have been included).

Comment: Alternative solution if you are trying to keep one form open, you need to make your own progress form. Use a label, do not use message box.